# How to find a match for the exact number in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a string, let say:

```
string s = "This is a test: 1234567";
int i = 1234567;
int j = 234567;
```

I want to find the exact match for the number 1234567 in the string s. 
I tried using Regex.IsMatch, but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is what I tried:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(^|\s)" + i.ToString() + @"(\s|$)") // This should yield true. But it's not.
```

Any ideas?

Note: to be more explicit the number `j` does not exactly match the string `s`, it's only the number `i` which is an exact match in the string `s`.

Comment: Not completely clear to me. Would it also be valid to find j? If that is so, Jeppe's answer is probably the best.

Comment: You want to match on a word boundary. `\b1234567\b` worked for me [here](https://regex101.com/r/aQ6uK4/2) (I added `g` modifier so it continues matching to show where it does and doesn't work on different lines)

Comment: I just tried your code, and it is returning true on my machine.

Comment: Why regex? Not that it would work but why not look for ints and then compare those?

Comment: The code works on ideone: https://ideone.com/JefHGG

Comment: Your code works as expected on here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAg4kM

Comment: Apparently relevant link, [MSDN: Anchors in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx)

Comment: So, It should return true for only "i" and not "j". It's wierd, I'm not sure why it's working for me. But, @Quantic's solution worked. I changed it to use:
`Regex.IsMatch(s,@'\b" + i.ToString() + @"\b")`
and it worked perfectly .

Thank you all for your quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:*** I missed the point with `j` and `i`, cf. comments.

---

One simple way (avoiding `Regex`) is:

```
bool isMatch = s.Contains(i.ToString());
```

Documentation: [`Contains` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx): *Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.*

Comment: Note that this will also work for `This is a test: 12312345670000` (I'm guessing he wants to avoid this since he's using regular expressions).

Comment: I believe OP wants 1234567 to return true but for 234567 return false while your code will return true in both cases.

Comment: That is true. I want the exact match of 1234567. With Contains, it may return true for 234567 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the quick replies. @Quantic's solution:

```
Regex.IsMatch(s,@'\b" + i.ToString() + @"\b")
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

here, I have developed a *little algorithm* to help you with that:

```
bool Get(string s, int i)
{
    bool result = false;
    int index = s.IndexOf(i.ToString());
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            if (i.ToString().Length == s.Length)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(s.ElementAt(index + i.ToString().Length)))
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(s.ElementAt(index - 1)))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You may be using this as method in the following way:

```
bool result = Get(s, j);
```

Note: It is so long because it has to treat all the cases, but it seems it works, sorry for the ugly code!

Comment: Thank you! that's an interesting approach.

Comment: @Abhi You are welcome, hope it will help you, I have tested it with the numbers you have, and it worked. You are free to clean the code as you may want to.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks again!